# Promise object works in Javascript, but in Coffeescript result is not being passed to .then()

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This raw javascript works:

```
   function newStatusEvent(account, eventId, url, deferred, iteration) {
        var iteration = typeof iteration !== 'undefined' ? iteration : 0;
        url.get()
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.Automation.Status != "COMPLETED") {
                if (iteration < CHECK_ITERATIONS) {
                    iteration++;
                    $timeout(function (){
                        newStatusEvent(account, eventId, url,
                            deferred, iteration);
                    }, TIME_ITERATION);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject("failure");
                }
            } else {
                deferred.resolve("complete");
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

---

But in coffeescript:

```
  newStatusEvent = (account, eventId, url, deferred, iteration) ->
    iteration = (if typeof iteration isnt "undefined" then iteration else 0)
    url.get().then (data) ->
      console.log(data)
      unless data.Automation.Status is "COMPLETED"
        if iteration < CHECK_ITERATIONS
          iteration++
          $timeout (->
            newStatusEvent account, eventId, url, deferred, iteration
            return
          ), TIME_ITERATION
        else
          deferred.reject "failure"
      else
        deferred.resolve "complete"
      return
    deferred.promise
```

the `data` `url.get().then (data) ->` is undefined. In otherwards, the coffeescript version is not passing the result of a promised object...`data` to the `.then()` method. I imagine this is a coffee script thing because it works in javascript. What is going on?

Comment: You could check the javascript being compiled into by your coffeescript

Comment: You might want to say `iteration ?= 0` or `newStatusEvent = (account, eventId, url, deferred, iteration = 0) ->` to simplify things.

Comment: Well, now that you've changed your question, my answer is no longer relevant. The compiled code is here http://dpaste.com/1G5WNRW. And it looks fine. Your issue must be somewhere else.